# Twitter Profile Widget internal js doesn't work

Tags: 6, social-network

I'm trying to set up the [Twitter Profile Widget module](http://drupal.org/project/twitter_profile_widget) in another language instead of the default english.

To do so I need to modify the widget.js file, so I have to use the option "Internal" in the module admin panel in order to use my custom widget.js inside the module folder.

But if I select "Internal" the twitter messages aren't shown, I've checked the source code and the local widget.js it's loaded correctly

I have also replaced the default widget.js file from the module folder with the one in the external url: http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js, but still doesn't work

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?